# Drop rows from excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, rows, drop

I have a data that contains 15 rows by 4 columns, does anyone know how to delete every rows except row number 5, 10 and 15?

Figure below shows the input data, the whole highlighted rows would be the rows that I want to retain, in other words, I would like to delete row from 1 to 4, 6 to 9 and 11 to 14. Any help would be appreciated a lot, thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to selection by position

```py
df = pd.read_excel('d.xlsx',header=None)        # read file
df = df.iloc[[4,9,14]]                          # filter rows
df
     0  1   2  3
4    5  e   5  e
9   10  j  10  j
14   5  e   5  e
df.to_excel('d.xlsx',index=None,header=None)     # save file
```

**Update**
As per comment: To remove every 5th row from dataframe. Use [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) with [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/6075699). `df.drop(df.index[4::5])`

```py
df = pd.read_excel('d.xlsx',header=None)         # read file
df = df.drop(df.index[4::5])                     # drop every 5th rows
df.to_excel('d.xlsx',index=None,header=None)     # save file
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, is it possible to make loop for it? Because the actual data is quite large like thousand rows, could every 5th be deleted? Such as row of 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 and etc..

Comment: @EdisonToh please check Updated answer.